# Pre-loading background-image and 304 response

Tags: html, css, image, caching

I found that as I pre-loaded images used in background-image attributes, Safari browser (desktop and mobile) re-requested them which were already pre-loaded. (and Theire responses are 304 response.)

If the images are pre-loaded, Chrome browser (desktop and mobile) never request it again. It just show up at once.

But I should wait a few time in Safari because Safari re-request it for getting 304 response !

I don't want to be re-requested in Safari because if there are div tag which background-image is changed dynamically by its class, flickering happens whenever its class is changed.

It is not critical in Desktop but is really critical in Mobile.

How could I reach it ?

P.S.

Pre-loading can be taken by some way using img tag, explicit css background-image or content attributes, or javascript!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in a special situation.

In my website, I add the background-image to the BODY tag, and when users click the button, which i add an EventListener with callback function(change the background-image URL, and preload another image for next click).

When I test those features in local host environment(for which the href is 127.0.0.1), after click the whole page will blink/flick when change the background-image URL. I dig the HTTP res/rep with Wireshark, then found the Safari will re-request the same image(even it is been preloaded already).

Things strange comes, when test all over those features with the image server(which the href comes like www.abcdefgh.com/image/test_xxx.jpg, not IP address), the blink/flick has gone. Watch in the Wireshark, the re-request is also gone!